# Embedded ordering of elements of ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, collections, arraylist

I need to sort elements subject to two parameters, `rank` and `dist` (embedded ordering). Firstly, elements must be ordered subject to `rank` values in descending order. Secondly, these ordered elements must be re-ordered according to `dist` values in descending order.

Example:

```
rank = [8.0, 2.0, 8.0, 5.0, 2.0]
dist = [1.2, 2.2, 3.1, 1.1, 0.8]

Step 1: ordered rank = [8.0, 8.0, 5.0, 2.0, 2.0], indexes = [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]

Step 2: ordered dist = [3.1, 1.2, 1.1, 2.2, 0.8], indexes = [2, 0, 3, 1, 4]
```

So, final result is `indexes = [2, 0, 3, 1, 4]`. The idea is that in Step 2 we can swap only those elements that have same ranks.

My current version of the code is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    ArrayList<Double> rank = new ArrayList<Double>();
    rank.add(8.0);
    rank.add(2.0);
    rank.add(5.0);
    rank.add(1.0);
    rank.add(2.0);
    rank.add(8.0);

    ArrayList<Double> dist = new ArrayList<Double>();
    dist.add(1.8);
    dist.add(2.8);
    dist.add(1.1);
    dist.add(2.1);
    dist.add(2.2);
    dist.add(1.5);

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
    result.add(0,rank);
    result.add(1,dist);

    System.out.println(result.get(0));

    ArrayList<Double> nstore1 = new ArrayList<Double>(result.get(0));
    Collections.sort(result.get(0));
    int[] indexes1 = new int[result.get(0).size()];
    for (int n = 0; n < result.get(0).size(); n++){
        indexes1[n] = nstore1.indexOf(result.get(0).get(result.get(0).size()-n-1));
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexes1));

}
```

I got stuck with Step 2. How to make re-ordering of elements subject to `dist`, while considering the order of ranks? Any intuitive example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think it will be better to write your own comparator.

Comment: @Achintya Jha: How to do this in such a way that in Step 2 we can swap only those elements that have the same rank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class SortObject {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Student[] students = new Student[4];

        Student one = new Student(8.0, 1.8);
        Student two = new Student(2.0, 2.8);
        Student three = new Student(5.0, 1.1);
        Student four = new Student(1.0, 2.1);

        students[0] = one;
        students[1] = two;
        students[2] = three;
        students[3] = four;

        // Arrays.sort(students, Student.StudentComparator); // to sort on basis
        // of both rank and dist

        Arrays.sort(students);

        int i = 0;
        for (Student temp : students) {
            System.out.println("fruits " + ++i + " : " + temp.getRank()
                    + ", Quantity : " + temp.getDist());
        }

    }
}
```

Copy and try this. And let me know it solves problem or not.

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {

    private Double rank;
    private Double dist;

    public Student(double rank, double dist) {

        this.rank = rank;
        this.dist = dist;

    }

    public Double getRank() {
        return rank;
    }

    public Double getDist() {
        return dist;
    }

    public int compareTo(Student student) {

        return (int) (student.rank - this.rank);

    }

    public static Comparator<Student> StudentComparator = new Comparator<Student>() {

        public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {

            Double first = student1.dist;
            Double second = student2.dist;

            return (int) (second - first);

        }

    };
}
```

Comment: You just answered his homework question.  Now he'll just copy this instead of learning something.

Comment: It's possible to sort by `dist` and `rank` with a single method.

Comment: @toto2 Yes , I wrote code for that one.Otherwise Array.sort() works fine for single double array.

Comment: Thanks. I checked your code. In fact, it sorts by the first parameter, but it does not sort according to Step 2 of my example. Well, I'll try to figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using primitives, you need to create your own object, and [comparators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to help you sort.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I have invented:

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      ArrayList<Double> r = new ArrayList<Double>();
      r.add(8.0);
      r.add(2.0);
      r.add(5.0);
      r.add(1.0);
      r.add(2.0);
      r.add(8.0);
      ArrayList<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
      d.add(1.8);
      d.add(2.8);
      d.add(1.1);
      d.add(2.1);
      d.add(2.2);
      d.add(1.5);
      Double[] rank = r.toArray(new Double[r.size()]);
      Double[] dist = d.toArray(new Double[d.size()]);
      Arrays.sort(rank);
      int fromIndex = -1;
      int indexes = 0;
      double lastValue;
      for (int a = 0; a < rank.length; a++) {
         lastValue = rank[a];
         if (lastValue == rank[a]) {
            if (fromIndex == -1) {
               fromIndex = a;
            }
            indexes++;
         } else {
            Arrays.sort(rank, fromIndex, indexes);
            fromIndex = -1;
            indexes = 0;
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Rank: " + Arrays.toString(rank));
      System.out.println("Dist: " + Arrays.toString(dist));
   }
}
```

Im not sure if this is what you were thinking so let me know if its okay. Writing comparator which would sort array in decrease-way will be your task (as your question is a homework question).

Comment: It would be nice if you can post an example for the case of two parameters. Well, Map is fine. Thanks.

Comment: While you can make it work with maps, that won't be a elegant solution, not to mention anti-OO.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is clearly a homework question, I won't give you a full answer.

I agree with others who said you will have to write your own `Comparator`s.  I think this is actually a pretty good question to force you to think in an Object Oriented way.  You need to think first about what is the fundamental data unit (basic Java class) in this problem.  Hint: it is quite orthogonal from the way the data is presented.